# Swift 4 - Can't call delegate method

Tags: ios, swift

I have one `delegate` method defined in one `viewController` like so:

```
import UIKit

protocol PatientsUserDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {

    func patientsUserDelegateMethod()

}

class PatientsUserController: UIViewController {

    var patientsUserDelegate: PatientsUserDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        print("Here")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func nextButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        patientsUserDelegate?.patientsUserDelegateMethod()

    }

}
```

What I am trying to do is call this delegate method in another `viewController` like so:

```
class PatientsRegistration: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, PatientsUserDelegate {

   var patientsUserController = PatientsUserController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

         patientsUserController.patientsUserDelegate = self

    }

    func patientsUserDelegateMethod() {
        print("Here")
    }

}
```

nextButtonPressed gets called but not the delegate method is not being called in the first `viewController` I have. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We do not see the code where you actually set the delegate.. Could you include that code? Or is that done in a Storyboard?

Comment: I updated my question where I actually set the delegate.

Comment: Glad you got your answer!  Note that if you setup an override, you should typically call the `super.viewDidLoad()` or whatever method it is you are overriding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
var patientsUserController = PatientsUserController()
```

The trouble is that this is not the same PatientsUserController that you actually want to talk to. It is a new PatientsUserController, a different one, that just floats in mid-air, with no relation to your running program. Thus, when you set the delegate...

```
patientsUserController.patientsUserDelegate = self
```

...you have set the delegate of the wrong PatientsUserController.

This is such a common beginner mistake that I've written a blog post about it:

http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

As you'll see when you read that post, you need to get yourself a reference to the *real* PatientsUserController, the one that is already existing in your view controller hierarchy. How you do that depends on the relationship between your various view controllers.